# next.js nested dynamic routes

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, dynamic-routing

I am stucked with a nextjs specific issue, and hope you can help me, because I cannot make this work for about 2 days.

I would like to have nested dynamic routes for our FAQ page:

baseurl/help/[maincategory]/[subcategory]/[helpid]
this would be the expected url format:

my folder structure (pages folder):

[image]

This is the folder structure.
The index.js would show all of the questions which are in the maincategory/subcategory and the [help].js would show the specific id help question detailed.

I don’t know what is going on, but it is clearly not working.

For eg: here is the [help].js

```
import React from 'react'
import { BuilderComponent, Builder, builder } from '@builder.io/react'

export async function getStaticPaths(context) {
  //console.log(context)

  const pages = await builder.getAll('help-data', {
    options: {
      noTargeting: true,
      query: {
        'data.tabId': 'helpmap',
      },
      omit: 'data.blocks',
    },
  })

  let routes = []

  const result = pages.map((item) => {
    item.data.mainTabList.map((main, mainidx) => {
      main.subTabList.map((sub, subidx) => {
        //console.log(main.tab + '  #  ' + sub.tab)
        routes.push({
          maincategory: main.tab.replace(/\s/g, '-'),
          subcategory: sub.tab.replace(/\s/g, '-'),
          help: `${mainidx}${subidx}`,
        })
      })
    })
  })

  const paths = routes.map((doc) => ({
    params: {
      maincategory: `${doc.maincategory.toLowerCase()}`,
      subcategory: `${doc.subcategory.toLowerCase()}`,
      help: doc.help,
    },
  }))

  console.log(paths)
  console.log('############################################')

  return {
    paths: paths,
    fallback: false,
  }
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  console.log(context.params)
  const { maincategory, subcategory, help } = context.params

  return {
    props: {
      maincategory,
      subcategory,
      help,
    },
    revalidate: 5,
  }
}

const index = ({ maincategory, subcategory, help }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>{maincategory}</div>
      <div>{subcategory}</div>
      <div>{help}</div>
    </>
  )
}

export default index
```

Here is the result of the console.log(paths)

```
[
  {
    params: {
      maincategory: 'business',
      subcategory: 'common-questions',
      help: '00'
    }
  },
  {
    params: {
      maincategory: 'business',
      subcategory: 'open-and-manage-a-shop',
      help: '01'
    }
  },
  {
    params: { maincategory: 'business', subcategory: 'send-money', help: '02' }
  },
  {
    params: {
      maincategory: 'business',
      subcategory: 'receive-money',
      help: '03'
    }
  },
  {
    params: { maincategory: 'business', subcategory: 'limits', help: '04' }
  },
 etc...
  {
    params: {
      maincategory: 'complaint',
      subcategory: 'raise-the-limits-of-your-business-account',
      help: '35'
    }
  }
]
```

############################################

So the returned result is the expected.
And although I visit a correct url, the getstaticprops won’t be called. And I cannot figure it why…
[image: image image 1053×441 8.08 KB]

Eg the last route example:

> http://localhost:3000/hu/helpa/complaint/raise-the-limits-of-your-business-account/35/

It is strange, because fallback=false, so if this site not valid, it should be 404, but instead it's an empty page,and getstaticprops not called, so it did not find the url?

The [[…page.tsx]] can cause issue? I don’t know, I really hope you can help me find the problem.

Comment: what is the result of `console.log(context.params)` in `getStaticProps` ? and did you implement the internationalized routing using i18n or any other solution?

Comment: (Yes ofc I have i18n for the routing), and no result, because getstaticprops won't get called. because according to next.js documentation: If fallback is false, then any paths not returned by getStaticPaths will result in a 404 page. Currently I go with fallback: 'blocking' this way the getstaticprops fires, but I have no idea why not with fallback: false

Comment: did you fix this issue?

Comment: no, because I don't understand why is getstaticprops not getting called with a proper url (like in the example above in my question)

Comment: I think the issue is, you should return the `locale` with the paths, not inside `params`, something like `{ params { }, locale}` , what is the `defaultLocale` that you specified in `next.config.js` ?